# How to increase Postman Client request timeout

Tags: postman

I am requesting an API from postman and getting response after 2 minutes, which is fine because the business logic is complex. But the problem is that postman is giving

> 502 Bad Gateway

After that, I checked the business logic and found that it successfully executed without any error.

So my concern is how to increase the request time.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future - although the responses below are correct with regards to how to increase Postman timeout, none of them point to the real problem the OP seems to be having.  You do not get a 502 Bad Gateway from a client-side timeout - a 502 _is_ a response.  You are getting a response before you are timing out client-side.  What I strongly suspect is happening here is that the client is accessing the API via a load balancer or some other type of network device and that device is configured to time out after 120 secs, at which point the device returns the 502.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

What version of postman do you use? 
In version [4.1.3](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/settings) I have XHR Timeout(ms) which means :

- Set how long the app should wait for a response before saying that the server isn't responding.

***Settings -> general ->XHR Timeout(ms)***
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for a single query?

Answer (score 32):

For POSTMAN client new version go to
**Settings-->General-->Request timeout in ms (0 for infinity)**

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to specify timeout in milliseconds.  Add 3 zeros if you want seconds.

Comment: is it possible to set the timeout for collections too ?

Answer (score 10):

Request timeout setting option in the latest version **v10.8.1**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
XHR Timeout(ms)
```

Set how long the app should wait for a response before saying that the server isn't responding.

> Go to settings -> general ->XHR Timeout(ms) set it to 120000